# have multiple users as one model field in many to one format django models

Tags: python, django, model, one-to-many

I want to create a minimalist task management app to learn Django's basics. So there will be Projects , Tasks and Users as the three big entities.

- A Project can have multiple users
- A Project can have multiple tasks
- A task can be assigned to 1 user

I can unable to figure out how to do a Many-to-One from Project - > Users using `django.contrib.auth.models.User` as my Users source.

This is what I have so far, but I know it is wrong and I am unable to wrap my head around it. I tried to relate to other questions such as the one with Contestents and the one with Vulnerabilities URLS on StackOverflow. I am not sure if I have to write my own User Model, or somehow extend it.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    Project_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Project_Users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class Tasks(models.Model):
    Task_Name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    Task_AssignedToUser = models.ForeignKey("Project_Name", through=Users)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='project_tasks')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tasks')
```

Get the the users participating in a specific project:

```
p = Project.objects.get(name='myproject')
users = p.users.all()
```

Get a project's tasks:

```
users = p.project_tasks.all()  # Because of `related_name` in Task.project
```

Get All the tasks a user has, of all the projects:

```
u = User.objects.get(username='someuser')
u.tasks.all()  # Because of `related_name` in Task.assignee
```

Notes:

1. A `ForeignKey` is a Many to One relationship. e.g. A Task belongs to only one Project - A Project can have many Tasks.
2. You don't need superfluous field names. `name` is better than `Project_Name`
3. One question at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I fill follow your three notes as well. How does this prevent me from assigning one task to a user who is not within the project from the Django Admin?

Comment: @kal Don't hesitate to ask for clarifications and/or post more questions for individual issues.

Comment: @kal It doesn't. You have to write code that takes care of that, since this is a `business logic` issue and not a `constraint` that can be enforced at the database level.